# what does this method signature mean

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, block

I'm looking at the source code for AFNetworking (and am noob at Objective-C and AFNetworking) and am trying to understand some inherited code. It looks like they are blocks that return nothing, pass in an AFHTTPRequestOperation and either the response or the NSError. Is this a block definition? What does the success / failure at the end signify? I'm  thinking it's something like success:MyParam(NSString *)my_param. Just like a single sentence would suffice.

```
- (void)getPath:(NSString *)path
     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
```

Any help is appreciated. Thx in advance

Comment: `success` and `failure` are the names of the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `success` and `failure` parameters are blocks, an extension to the C programming language by Apple. A block is very similar to an anonymous function pointer.

It plays the role of a drop-in call-back function in this scenario. If the path were successfully got, `success` call-back would be invoked, or the `failure` call-back would be invoked.

The signature specified what parameters these call-back blocks should accept, respectively. The actual values of these parameters would be provided by this AFNetworking call.

Comment: thx - let me look through and see if I can figure out how success is getting defined

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those are blocks. The first thing you see, the `success`/`failure` at the beginning, is part of the method's name and is what you would put before that argument when you pass it to the method. The `void` indicates the block returns no value. The `^` screams "I'm a block!" at you. The block takes two arguments; a `AFHTTPRequestOperation *` which is known as `operation` inside the block and an `id` which is known as `responseObject` inside the block. The `success`/`failure` at the end is the name of the whole block argument that is used to reference it inside the method receiving it.